# Mutual authentication of python processes

Tags: python, authentication

Imagine you have two python processes, one server and one client, that interact with each other.
Both processes/programs run on the same host and communicate via TCP, eg. by using the AMP protocol of the twisted framework.

Could you think of an **efficient and smart** way how both python programs can authenticate each other?
What I want to achieve is, that for instance the server only accepts a connection from an authentic client and where not allowed third party processes can connect to the server.

I want to avoid things like public-key cryptography or SSL-connections because of the huge overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use SSL - there are a few options:

1. Client must send some authentication token (you may call it password) to server as a one of the first bunch of data sent through the socket. This is the simplest way. Also this way is cross-platform.
2. Client must send id of his process (OS-specific). Then server must make some system calls to determine path to executable file of this client process. If it is a valid path - client will be approved. For example valid path should be `'/bin/my_client'` or `"C:\Program Files\MyClient\my_client.exe"` and if some another client (let's say with path `'/bin/some_another_app'` will try to communicate with your server - it will be rejected. But I think it is also overhead. Also implementation is OS-specific.